# How can I read messages from NSQ channel with aiohttp application

Tags: python-3.x, tornado, python-asyncio, aiohttp, pynsq

There is a good library **pynsq**, it uses tornado inside, so for example when I create simple tornado app, then there I can instantiate nsq.Reader instance, then when I start tornado server, this nsq.Reader() instance starts to work.

In case when I want to use **aiohttp** as web server - what is modern and proper way to have nsq reader there ?

Comment: I the library is missing -- write it :)

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov thank you for answer :)

Comment: There is https://github.com/aohan237/asyncnsq but I'm not sure what state it is in.